# Can't load 'Caret' in R

Tags: r, r-caret

When loading the `caret` package the following error appears.

```
> library(caret)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’:
 object ‘warnErrList’ is not exported by 'namespace:utils'
```

Even I tried to install 'caret' with all dependencies, it still shows: object ‘warnErrList’ is not exported by 'namespace:utils'

Comment: Hi, what OS and which version of R are you using. I have no problems on Windows 10 and R 3.5.1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Xu Gao, the `caret` maintainer believes that if you update to the most-recent version of `caret`, this should go away (https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/1041#issuecomment-498486222). Did you try `install.packages("caret")` before updating R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xu Gao, it is likely that you are on a version of R prior to 3.5.0. Either you will need to upgrade R, or downgrade whatever package is dependent on it.

If you read [R-devel NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html), search for `warnErrList`, and you'll find

> New warnErrList() utility (from package nlme, improved)

You can back this up by looking at the list of exported functions for [`utils` in R-3.5.0](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.5.0) and you can find `warnErrList`, whereas [`utils` in R-3.4.3](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.4.3) (the previous release of R), the function cannot be found.

Unfortunately, I cannot find `utils::warnErrList` in the [`caret` source](https://github.com/topepo/caret/) directly, which suggests one of its dependencies might be using it and you find out about it late in the game. If you run `traceback()` immediately after receiving that error, it may provide some insight as to which package is trying to use it. (Some sleuthing will likely be required, searching for function names, even those that are not exported by the intermediate packages.)

Also, I request that you please submit a [`caret` issue](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/new?title=require+R+>%3D+3.5.0), including the steps necessary to justify the bug. (I could start an issue, but because I have R-3.5.3, caret-6.0.80, and I cannot reproduce the bug ... it could be disingenuous of me to file the bug ... not to mention that I might be completely wrong about this :-)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! It's solved after I upgrad R.

Comment: Great! Please "accept" the answer, it'll help close it out for future similar questions.

Comment: Did you ever find out what package or function was calling `utils::warnErrList`? It might be beneficial in the bug report to `caret` to inform of that. (Did you create the issue yet? Really, please do.)

Comment: I tried to accept the answer, but it showed: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: You can *always* "accept" your answer, which is different from the ability to up/down-vote an answer. Look for the checkmark under the voting arrows.

Comment: Do you have a github account? I have started a new issue (https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/1041), but since I don't know all of your details, my issue is incomplete. If you have a github account, please go there and comment on the issue with the output from `sessionInfo()` in general, and specifically `traceback()` *immediately* after triggering the error (on a fresh instance of R).